# sonar c# eco system: how to specify diffent binaries folder

Tags: sonarqube

I am actually evaluate sonar (sonarsource.org) for using it with c#.

Is it possible to specify a different binaries folder (MsBuild OutDir Property) for csharp projects? I use a custom OutDir on our build server to have the binaries/Buildoutput of every csharp project in one place.

Tried (with java runner and sonar-project.properties)

```
binaries=Binaries
```

And

```
sonar.gendarme.assemblies=Binaries/*.*
sonar.fxcop.assemblies=Binaries/*.*
```

BTW: how to specify search paths for gallio code coverage? My test assemblies are also not in bin/Debug.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that wild cards aren't possible. But: should the path to the assembly be relative or absolute? Relative...

```
File basedir = (vsProject == null) ? solution.getSolutionDir() : vsProject.getDirectory();
...
File file = new File(basedir, filePath);
```

But still  no success with 
sonar.fxcop.assemblies=../Binaries/Assembly1.dll;../Binaries/Assembly2.dll